# Fortran main program subroutines can link module variables but not module subroutines?

Tags: module, fortran, linker-errors, intel, subroutine

I have a module I made:

```
module my_sweet_module
complex, allocatable, volatile, save, private :: buffer_mem
integer mod_int1, mod_int2

contains

subroutine mod_sub1
include 'CRAPPY_OLD_IMPLICIT_PARAMETER_FILE'
<other code>
allocate(buffer_mem(CRAPPY_PARAMETER))
<more code>
end subroutine mod_sub1

end module my_sweet_module
```

When I `use` this module in my main file right after the `program` statement, I can reference the `integers` I declared in the modules no matter what scope I'm in--in fact, I had to refactor my code to rename any instances of `mod_int1` because of name collisions.

However, any time I want to use `mod_sub1` in a subroutine in my main file, I have to have a `use my_sweet_module` at the top of the subroutine or I get 'undefined reference' errors when I try to compile.

Example of my main file:

```
program my_prog
include 'ANOTHER_CRAPPY_OLD_IMPLICIT_PARAMETER_FILE'
use my_sweet_module
<code>
end program my_prog



subroutine main_sub1(args)
include 'EVEN_MORE_CRAPPY_OLD_IMPLICIT_PARAMETER_FILE'
!use my_sweet_module !uncomment this to fix errors
integer sub_int1

sub_int1=mod_int1+1 !Compiler is happy; doesn't give any error, even if it "should"
call mod_sub1 !compiler is unhappy, says "undefined reference to 'mod_sub1_'"
end subroutine main_sub1
```

Notes:

- I can't use `implicit none` in my module or my main file, because I am bolting this module onto some ancient code that uses implicit typing all over the place in `include`d files that I also need to use in my module
- Compiling with ifort version 5.243, in Linux, if it matters
- `mod_sub1` is not re-using a name, and is not being re-used as a name anywhere

I've 'solved' my issue on my own, but I am thoroughly confused.  I either shouldn't need to have `use` everywhere, or the compiler shouldn't be able to link in the global integers if I don't?  Either both `mod_int1` and `mod_sub1` should be out of scope or neither should be--the errors shouldn't be mixed-and-matched like this.

Comment: The `use` statement provides access to contents of a module within the scoping unit that contains the statement.  In what you have shown, `program my_prog` and `subroutine main_sub1` are independent scoping units, so if you need access to the module contents, then yes, you need to have a `use` statement in both.  Am I missing something.

Comment: Also if you want to have implicit none stick the includes in a module and then USE that module - that will give access to the variables without having to type them in the local scope if you use implicit none

Comment: @evets That makes sense, except that should mean `mod_int1` is out of scope in my example code when `use` is left out of `main_sub1`, but it doesn't give any compilation errors.  My problem is that either both `mod_sub1` and `mod_int1` should throw undefined reference errors, or neither should, but you have this situation where one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: You are using implicit typing.  mod_int1 is never out-of-scope.  It is a local variable to its scoping unit if you do not `use` the module.  `mod_sub1` in your module likely has its name mangled to something that cannot be confused with a user-defined symbol.  For example, gfortran will mangle the subroutine in the module to `__my_sweet_module_MOD_mod_sub1`.  If you are getting a link error, it likely refers to a missing `_mod_sub1` routine, because the expectation is that this is a user-defined routine which is not found.

Comment: uuuuuugh, I hate implicit typing.  Yeah, that's got to be it.

Comment: But wait, in my sample code (as well as my real code) `mod_int1` only appears on the right-hand side of an assignment operator in `main_sub1`.  So the code is implicitly allocating a real, adding one to the garbage it comes up with, and coercing that into an integer before storing it in `sub_int1` in my example, all without even giving a warning that an implicitly-typed variable only appears on the RHS of an equal sign?

Comment: Turn on all debug options.  It is the programmers responsibility to ensure a variable on the RHS of an expression is defined.